# Angular 2, redirect not working on refresh even with useHash

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an app which when refreshed I want to route to a component. Currently my app landing page look like

```
<div id="content" style="height:90%">
<div class="container container-fluid " style="height:100%; width:65%">
  <router-outlet style="margin-bottom:50px" class = "active dimmer"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

On refresh everything but the router outlet components refresh so I'm left with basically a header. So if I refresh on the login page I go from localhost:4400/login to localhost:4400 and I have to click a link to get to the page i was on. This is currently only a local project so a lot of the server stuff I've looked at has been relevent.

I tried using useHash:true in my routing:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true}),
```

But had no luck. I even tried redirecting on construction of the app component but that wouldn't work either. I can post more code if anything else is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

place  `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true})` as last import of the imports  array.